# How to find solution to $y'=y_1(x)g(x)+y_2(x)f(x)$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> How to find solution to $$y'=y_1(x)g(x)+y_2(x)f(x)$$

Asuume that function $y=y_1(x)$ is one of the solutions of differential equation $y'=f(x)$ as well as $y=y_2(x)$ of $y'=g(x)$. You need to find at least one solution of this equation:
$$y'=y_1(x)g(x)+y_2(x)f(x)$$

I am interested in methods of solving this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have

$$y'=y_1y_2'+y_2y_1'=(y_1y_2)'$$

And so a solution is $y(x)=y_1(x)y_2(x)$